# Program won't drop the lowest score and calculate the average without it

Tags: c++

Code works well except it doesn't drop the lowest score and then calculates it.

Output Example:

How many test scores would you like to enter?
3
Enter the test score desired:
Score 1: 58
Score 2: 96
Score 3: 78
Test Scores Average with the lowest dropped is: 116.00

Problem: 
As you can see on the output example, that is incorrect. It must display the average not including the lowest. Could you review my code and let me know where I have gone wrong? I've had several people look at it too and they've not been able to see any bugs in my code. Below is my code:

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //To dynamically allocate an array, Accumulator, to hold the average scores.
    double *score;      
    double total = 0;  
    double average; 


    //int for counter, to hold the number of test scores.
    int count; 
    int numTest; 


    // To obtain the number of test scores the user would like to enter.
    cout << "How many test scores would you like to enter? " << endl;
    cin >> numTest; 


    //Dynamically allocates an array large enough to hold the amount of test scores to enter.
    score = new double[numTest];


    //Get the test scores.
    cout << "Enter the test score desired. " << endl;
    for (count = 0; count < numTest; count++)
    {
        cout << "Score " << (count + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> score[count];
    }

    //Find lowest score.
    int lowest = score[count];
    for (count = 1; count < numTest; count++)
    {
        if (score[count] < lowest) 
            lowest = score[0];
    }


    //Calculate the total test scores.
    for (count = 0; count < numTest; count++)
    {
        total += score[count];
        total -= lowest;
    }

    //Calculate the test scores average minus the lowest score. 
    average = total / (numTest - 1);

    //Display the results
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Test Scores Average with the lowest dropped is: " << average << endl;

    //Free dynamically allocated memory
    delete [] score;
    score = 0; // Makes score point to null.

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new double[numTest];` - Eww. Try `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: Step through the code that finds the lowest score.

Comment: She wants us to use pointers and dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three significant errors in this code:

First, the initial value of `lowest`:

```
//Find lowest score.
int lowest = score[count];  // ERROR
for (count = 1; count < numTest; count++)
{
    if (score[count] < lowest) 
        lowest = score[0];
}
```

The error is here:

```
int lowest = score[count];
```

It needs to be this:

```
int lowest = score[0];
```

Next, **within the loop**:

```
lowest = score[0]; // ERROR
```

Should be:

```
lowest = score[count];
```

So your loop should look like this:

```
//Find lowest score.
int lowest = score[0];
for (count = 1; count < numTest; count++)
{
    if (score[count] < lowest) 
        lowest = score[count];
}
```

Finally, the calculation of the total is also wrong. Subtract the lowest score **after** calculating the total of all scores, *then* divide by the number of scores less-one:

```
//Calculate the total test scores.
for (count = 0; count < numTest; count++)
{
    total += score[count];
    total -= lowest; // ERROR: should not be here. should be AFTER the loop
}
```

Should be :

```
for (count = 0; count < numTest; count++)
    total += score[count];
total -= lowest; // note: NOT in the loop
```

Comment: OMG YOU ROCK!!!! IT works!!! Wooo hooo!!! I am so excited!! Thank you sooooo much!

Comment: @user1787078 Glad to help. You almost had it last night. You just put the lowest subtraction in the wrong place and put the initial value of lowest in the loop. Glad it works now.

Comment: Been new at this and exhausted of starring at a screen was frustrating. I can't thank you all enough for the huge help. I really learned a lot. My teacher is really non-existent so it's nice to know I can come some place and actually learn something. Happy Halloween!

Comment: @user1787078 you did it right. You had a clear question, provided code that was easy to read, short and concise, and **compiled**, and provided feedback to the people answering for you if they had questions about your post. Make this a habit, and StackOverflow can be *very* helpful.

Comment: @user1787078 No need. Between what you had and what is in the answers, everyone already generally knows.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
//Find lowest score.
int lowest = score[count];
```

your `count` variable is equal to `numTest` because you just left the preceding loop.

You should write

```
//Find lowest score.
int lowest = score[0]; // Error here
for (count = 1; count < numTest; count++)
{
    if (score[count] < lowest) 
        lowest = score[count]; // Error here too
}
```

Comment: I missed the first score[count] but I just changed that and now I get 29.00.

Answer (score 0):

The code subtracts `lowest` from `total` each time through the loop. Move that line outside the loop and it will work better.

EDIT: and, as @WhozCraig points out, `lowest` isn't getting the right initial value.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
int lowest = score[count];
```

what do you think `count` is?